# SQL-Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this assignment in SQL about stored procedures and I'm having a hard time understanding the question. So I can't come up with a solution.

Here's the question:

1. Write a stored procedure called `AddJobService` that will accept `JobNumber`, `ServiceCode`, Notes and Hours and will perform the following tasks: (8 marks)

a. If there is no job record with that `JobNumber` raise an appropriate message

b.  If there is a related job record, add a `JobService` record

c.  Adjust the appropriate columns in the Job table

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:

```
create procedure AddJobService (@JobNumber int = null, @ServiceCode varchar(15) = null, @Notes varchar(200) = null, @Hours int = null)
as
if @JobNumber is null
        Begin
        RaisError ('Please provide information', 16,1)
        End
else 
        if not exists(Select * from Job where JobNumber = @JobNumber)
        Begin
        RaisError (' Job Record Do not Exists ', 16,1)
        End

else
        begin
        Begin Transaction
        insert into JobService(ServiceCode, Notes, Hours)
        Values ( @ServiceCode, @Notes, @Hours)
        if @@ERROR <> 0
                Begin
                RaisError('Job Service Failed',16,1)
                Rollback Transaction
                End
        End
```

AND I'm getting this error
"
I can't actually do the 'C' part? I'm getting "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ExtCost', table 'LAB3.dbo.JobService'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated."

Comment: Show us what you achieved so far along with the schema

Comment: hi posted up what i have so far

Comment: What errors are you facing?

Comment: Let's get those 8 marks

Comment: Is it `sql-server` or `mysql`? Looks like `sql-server` to me. Also, `RaisError` should be `RaiseError`.

Comment: I can't actually do the 'C' part? I'm getting "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ExtCost', table 'LAB3.dbo.JobService'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: Might want to mention that error in your question. You've got a column 'ExtCost' into which you're trying to put a null value since you've only specified values for ServiceCode, Notes & Hours. You could try inserting a value or change the column definition to accept nulls.

Comment: uhm i dont have to show the ExtCost

Comment: Ok. but do you think my answer make sense? does it answers the given question? :x

Comment: Then maybe delete the column, and any other column you don't have to show.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you don't have to show `ExtCost` in your answer, however when you insert a record to table `JobService` , you are required to put in `ExtCost`.

If you can modify `JobService` table scheme, just change `ExtCost` to `nullable`, else you need to provide a value for `ExtCost`, perhaps '0'

```
insert into JobService(ServiceCode, Notes, Hours, ExtCost)
        Values ( @ServiceCode, @Notes, @Hours, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddJobService 
-- declaring input parameters 
@JobNumber INT, @ServiceCode INT, @Notes VARCHAR (50), @Hours INT 
AS 
BEGIN

-- if null replace with empty space
SET @JobNumber = ISNULL (@JobNumber, 0)
SET @ServiceCode = ISNULL (@ServiceCode, 0)
SET @Notes = ISNULL (@Notes, '')
SET @Hours = ISNULL (@Hours, 0)


IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Jobs WHERE JobNumber = @Jobnumber)
    --no record
    BEGIN
        RAISEERROR ('No information for that job number!',16,1);
    END
ELSE
    -- record
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Jobs (JobNumber, ServiceCode, Notes, [Hours])
        VALUES (@JobNumber, @ServiceCode, @Notes, @Hours)
    END
END GO
```

Comment: Thanks! And what about that "thart" in RAISEERROR? :))